# Search with a varable after https link

Tags: html, forms, button, search

im trying to make a search button that sets the searched article in a link.

example.com/zoeken?query=
after the = needs to be set the searched article.(so needs to be 'zoeken?query=article')

but when i try it it wil set a lot of random characters.
example.com/zoeken?query=&article=zena

```
<form action="https://pyroworks-demo.webshop.kei.io/zoeken?query=" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="query">
    <input type="text" name="article" placeholder="article">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Can someone help me with this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="">
    <form action="https://pyroworks-demo.webshop.kei.io/zoeken?query=" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="query">
        <input type="text" name="article" placeholder="article">
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `query=` in your action.
The form submit will automatically append all input `name` attributes, as query parameters, as long as the `method` is `get`

So simply do like this:

```html
<form action="https://pyroworks-demo.webshop.kei.io/zoeken" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="article">
   <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```